# Escaping single and double quotes in Regex inside vee validate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I cannot get my head around how to escape single and double quotes in this case:

```
v-validate="{ min:3, max:200, url:true, regex: /^(http)?s?:?(\/\/[^"']*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg))$/}"
```

Comment: Do you have some sample strings to test?

Comment: I would just move that object definition into your script and out of the template.

Answer (score 2):

regex.html

```
<input v-validate="{ regex: regex }" />
```

regex.vue

```
...
data: {
    regex: /^(http)?s?:?(\/\/[^"']*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg))$/
}
...
```